# how to group by function if any one of the group members has neighbor relationship with another any one of group member in the group?

Tags: python

**update1:
if same color is neighbor like connected then group them**

how to group by function if any one of the group members has neighbor relationship with another any one of group member in the group?

```
if x coordinate same and y coordinate difference is 1 then return 1 #same memeber
if y coordinate same and x coordinate difference is 1 then return 1 #same memeber
else return 0 #not group memeber
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: isneighborlocation() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

```
from itertools import groupby 

testing1 = [(1,1),(2,3),(2,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,6)] 
def isneighborlocation(lo1, lo2): 
    if abs(lo1[0] - lo2[0]) == 1  or lo1[1] == lo2[1]: 
        return 1 
    elif abs(lo1[1] - lo2[1]) == 1  or lo1[0] == lo2[0]: 
        return 1 
    else: 
        return 0 

groupda = groupby(testing1, isneighborlocation) 
for key, group1 in groupda: 
    print key 
    for thing in group1: 
        print thing 



expect output 3 group 
group1 [(1,1)] 
group2 [(2,3),(2,4)] 
group3 [(3,5),(3,6),(4,6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function argument in `groupby` accepts a single argument, so you have to make use of partial functions to add the 'extra' one.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial

```
from functools import partial 
...
groupda = groupby(testing1, partial(isneighborlocation, centre))
```

but, of course, it means that you have to explicitly test every 'centre'.
Btw, be aware of the sorting requirement on groupby - it seems likely that it may trip you up.

Comment: i do not know what center is, actually there is no center, if same color is connected then group it, just that goal, how to use partial function with groupby , can you write solution explicitly?